# Build UL LIST using regular expression PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, html-lists

I'm new to PHP and Regular Expression so I would someone help me to build a UL List from simple text. Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

Input:

> Transportation.
>   Accommodation.

Output:

```
<ul>
<li>Transportation</li>
<li>Accommodation</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you really need a regex for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this. You can change delimiter by replacing  "\n".

Demo: http://ideone.com/IuK2D7

```
$text=  "Transportation.
         Accommodation.";

$exploded =  explode("\n",$text);

echo "<ul>" . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($exploded as $line) {

   echo "<li>" . $line . "</li>" . PHP_EOL; 

}

echo "</ul>" . PHP_EOL;
```

This would give you an output like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Transportation</li>
<li>Accommodation</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit** : For cross compatibility across multiple operating systems, you can use this:

```
$exploded =  explode(PHP_EOL,$text);
```

This ensures the right line break is used within the OS which the code is being executed in. As a commentator pointed it, this would handle Mac, Linux and Windows operating systems. Good luck!

Comment: Windows ends lines in `\r\n`, Linux/UNIX in `\n`, and Mac in `\r`

Comment: Then he can use the PHP_EOL constant, which makes it cross compatible.

Comment: proper fix with `PHP_EOL` +1